# Adding channel to dataset for multichannel sequence analysis in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset which I am trying to run sequence analysis on. I am considering using both multi-channel analysis and alphabet expansion. Multi-channel analysis for behaviors **which overlap but do not occur at the same time** and alphabet expansion **which do occur at the same time.**
So, in essence, this dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  behavior = c('AU2', 'AU4', 'AU6', 'AU8', '9', 'AU6', 'AU1', 'AU2', 'AU5', 'AU5'),
  start = c(2.4, 14.84, 17.64, 22.08, 22.2, 23.92, 66.92, 66.92, 67.88, 79.52),
  stop = c(80.72, 15.68, 18.12, 22.4, 22.4, 24.6, 68.48, 68.48, 69.76, 80.72),
  Duration_s = c(78.32, 0.84, 0.48, 0.32, 0.2, 0.68, 1.56, 1.56, 1.88, 1.2)
)
```

would look like this:

```
 id = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  behavior = c("AU2", "AU4", "AU6", "AU8", "9", "AU6", "AU1+AU2", "AU5", "AU5"),
  start = c(2.4, 14.84, 17.64, 22.08, 22.2, 23.92, 66.92, 67.88, 79.52),
  stop = c(80.72, 15.68, 18.12, 22.4, 22.4, 24.6, 68.48, 69.76, 80.72),
  channel = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2),
  Duration_s = c(78.32, 0.84, 0.48, 0.32, 0.2, 0.68, 1.56, 1.88, 1.2)
)
```

Start and Stop in this dataset refer to the time stamp at which the behavior started/ stopped in seconds. I have used the following code for the alphabet expansion part:

```
#Add position
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(start) %>%
  mutate(position = dense_rank(start))

#Combine AU's which start at the same time
df_combined <- df %>%
  group_by(id, position) %>%
  summarise(turn_type = paste(behavior, collapse = " + "))
```

which works great but I cannot figure out to add the channel column using the time stamps. Thanks in advance!